# Rebuilding String with String split Java

Tags: java, string, split

I'm writing a program that will take sheet music (chords above lyrics) and transpose the key.  I'm choosing to split up a song String, manipulate the chord names and build a new String.  My approach is to split the song into lines `String[] holder = song.split("\\n+");`  Then, take each line and split based on whitespace `String[] oneLine = s.split("\\s");`

When building the new string, maintaining the original spacing is absolutely crucial.  My problem is that by splitting on //s I lose all history of spacing.  Can anyone suggest a solution to my problem?

Here is an example song

```
String song = "G   Em  C   D\nSome Lyrics Go Here\nG   C   D\nOther Lyrics Go Here";
```

Currently my transposed song would look like this...

```
AF#mDE
Some Lyrics Go Here
ADE
Other Lyrics Go Here
```

Comment: Do you mean from `G   Em  C   D` you want to change to `A F#m D E` with the white-space before? But because you trying to change it than the white-space become disappear? Can you post the code when you trying to change the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `StringTokenizer` to split the string, it can be configured to retain and return the delimiters as well.  This way, you can maintain the number of spaces.

See the [`StringTokenizer(String,String,boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) constructor.

> **public StringTokenizer(String str,
>                                 String delim,
>                                 boolean returnDelims)**
>
> Constructs a string tokenizer for the specified string. All characters in the `delim` argument are the delimiters for separating tokens.
>
> If the `returnDelims` flag is true, then the delimiter characters are also returned as tokens. Each delimiter is returned as a string of length one. If the flag is false, the delimiter characters are skipped and only serve as separators between tokens.
>
> Note that if `delim` is null, this constructor does not throw an exception. However, trying to invoke other methods on the resulting StringTokenizer may result in a NullPointerException.
>
> **Parameters:**
>         `str` - a string to be parsed.
>         `delim` - the delimiters.
>         `returnDelims` - flag indicating whether to return the delimiters as tokens.

Comment: I've used the tokenizer before, but didn't realize it had this functinality.  I'll give it a shot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `String.split()` which, as you have noticed, will discard your spacing, you'll need to  use some other technique. You can simply process each line one character at a time in a loop, appending each character as its it processed to a `StringBuilder`, such that you end up with the same number of characters altogether at the end.